# Excel formula: unnecessary extra steps in SUMIF process

Tags: excel, math

It seems like I'm overlooking a very simple math formula (ideally without "if's") to do this from the start.

Not looking for a programming or spreadsheet solution, all within one cell, to solve this in multiple steps -- I can combine all that myself.  Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems I'm breaking apart a very simple mathematical / algebraic solution into a number of unnecessary steps.

```
A    | B      | C    | D    | E        | F |  
:- - | :----- | :--- | :--- | :----    | :----------- |  
Rank | Col B | Col C | B+C  | Formula1 | B+C+Formula2 |  
1    |  700  |  20   |  720 |          |  849  |  
2    |  680  |  1    |  681 |          |  810  |  
3    |  679  |  1    |  680 |       5  |  809  |  
4    |  678  |  5    |  683 |       7  |  807  |  
5    |  673  |  7    |  680 |      11  |  797  |  
6    |  666  |  11   |  677 |      30  |  783  |  
7    |  655  |  30   |  685 |          |  761  |  
8    |  625  |  5    |  630 |          |  706  |  
9    |  620  |  1    |  621 |       2  |  697  |  
10   |  619  |  2    |  621 |       3  |  695  |  
11   |  617  |  3    |  620 |       8  |  691  |  
12   |  614  |  8    |  622 |          |  685  |  
13   |  606  |  1    |  607 |       5  |  670  |  
14   |  605  |  5    |  610 |      40  |  668  |  
15   |  600  |  40   |  640 |          |  658  |  
16   |  560  |  1    |  561 |       2  |  579  |  
17   |  559  |  2    |  561 |       6  |  577  |  
18   |  557  |  6    |  563 |      10  |  573  |  
19   |  551  |  10   |  561 |          |  561  |  
20   |  541  |  1    |  542 |          |  542  |
```

Hi, for this table, I've taken a couple steps.
1) In Column C,

```
=SUM($b2,-$b3)
```

2) In Column D,

```
=SUM($b2,$c2)
```

3) In Column E,

```
=IF(SUM($d2,-$d3)<SUM($b2,-$b3),$c3,"")
```

*At this step, I'm ensuring that all Column D records ("B+C") maintain at least as much distance above the next record, as they originally did in Column B.*

4) In Column F,

```
=SUM($d2,$e2:$e$21)
```

*Now adding every single Column E figure to all figures above it.*

Comment: Is this in Excel? If so, it should be tagged with the `excel` tag. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also, it seems you don't actually ask a question, so it's a bit unclear what you're hoping to achieve here...

Comment: Thanks, guys -- I know it's an unusual post.  It's not an excel q, but looking for a simple math equation (possibly algebraic) that I might be overlooking -- one that does not involve if's -- that gets me the same result.  Seems I'm wasting a trip around the block when there's a basic math formula staring me in the face.

Comment: Oh - you're not worried about making a spreadsheet, you're just using a spreadsheet to test out your algebra? Maybe this is a question for [Math stack exchange?](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks!  didn't know about that -- i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

So we have

```
C2 = B2 - B3, 
C3 = B3 - B4, .....
D2 = B2 + C2 = 2 * B2 - B3, 
D3 = B3 + C3 = 2 * B3 - B4, ....

E2 = if( D2 - D3 < B2 - B3 , C3 , 0 )
E2 = if( (2 * B2 - B3) - (2 * B3 - B4) < (B2 - B3), B3 - B4, 0)
E2 = if( 2 * B2 - B3 - 2 * B3 + B4) < B2 - B3, B3 - B4, 0)
E2 = if( 2 * B2 - 3 * B3 + B4 < B2 - B3, B3 - B4, 0)
E2 = if( B2 - 2 * B3 + B4 < 0 , B3 - B4, 0)
E2 = if( B2 + B4 < 2 * B3, B3 - B4, 0)
E2 = if( (B2 + B4)/2 < B3, B3 - B4, 0)
```

So E2 is basically seeing if B3 is greater than the mean of B2+B4.

I can't see a way to easily simplify the column F formula. It could be written in terms of a SUMIF but you probably would need an extra column with 2*B3 - B2 - B4 in it.

It does seem a little unusual as it is more typical to do cumulative sums rather than the acculumation from the bottom.

Comment: What would the cumulative sums look like, or any other solutions?

The goals of the math are to
1) Keep the data in the same order (nth largest value remains nth largest)
2) Each difference from value (n) - value (n+1) must remain at least as big as its original difference.

   .....I had an earlier solution for column E that basically said anytime a value (n) in column D was less than value (n+1) in column D, add column C to value (n) and all values above it.  That kept the final column in order, but failed to maintain the differences between each sequential pair of values.